# Ports On Docker

Tags: azure, docker, port

Is there a way to bind ports to containers without passing an argument via the run command? I do not like starting my containers with the 'docker run' command so using the -p argument is not an option for me. I like to start my containers with the 'docker start containername' command. I would like to specify the hostname of the docker-server with the port number (http://dockerserver:8081) and this should then be forwarded to my container's app which is listening on port 8081. My setup is on Azure but is pretty basic so the Azure docker plugin looks a bit like overkill. I read up about the expose command but seems like you still need to use the 'docker run -p' command to get access to the container from the outside. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`docker run` is just a shortcut for `docker create` + `docker start`. Ports need to be exposed when a container is created, so the `-p` option is available in [docker create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/):

```
docker create -d -p 80:80 --name web nginx:alpine
docker start web
```

Port publishing only does ports though.

If you want the hostname passed to the container, you'll need to do it with a command option or (more likely) an environment variable - defined with `ENV` in the Dockerfile and passed with `-e` in `docker create`.

Comment: Sorry but I was a bit confused when I asked the question. I actually did create named containers with the "docker run" command and then started it using the "docker start {container name}" command. Your answer did point me in the right direction but I did not use the "docker create" command. Instead I used "docker run" and specified the port with -p. The great thing is that it even worked for multiple ports (just had to specify -p port:port for each port I wanted. After this I started the docker with the "docker start {container name}" and it worked. Thank you for your assistance.